# Is there any material on this simpler version of Littlewood's Conjecture?

Tags: real-analysis, conjectures

[Littlewood's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood_conjecture) is defined as follows:

> For any real number $x$, define $f(x)$ as the distance between $x$ and the integer nearest to $x$,
> or $f(x) = \min(x - \lfloor x \rfloor, \lceil x \rceil - x)$.

> The statement of the conjecture is that for any two real numbers $\alpha$, $\beta$, $$\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ n  \cdot  f(n\alpha) \cdot f(n\beta) = 0$$ taking the $\liminf$ for positive integer values of $n$.

Since the conjecture uses a pair of numbers, it would make sense to consider a "simpler" version of the conjecture, using a single real number only. However, I couldn't find anything on that matter.

> For all real number $\alpha$, does $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ n \cdot f(n\alpha) = 0?$, Again, we take the $\liminf$ for positive integer values of $n$.

According to the Wikipedia article, Borel(1909) showed that the number of pairs $(\alpha, \beta)$ violating the $2$-variable version is a set of measure zero, and the $2$-variable version connects to future conjectures in group theory. Therefore, I have some questions:

- Is there any proof / counterexample / discussion of my $1$-variable version?
- Are there further connections and/or implications to other problems for the $1$-variable version?
- What about generalisations to $n$-tuples of real values in $\mathbb{R}^n$?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: since $0 \le f \le 1/2$ it follows that $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ n  \cdot  f(n\alpha) = 0$ implies $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ n  \cdot  f(n\alpha) \cdot f(n\beta) = 0$ for all $\beta$; for quadratic irrationals $\liminf_{n \rightarrow \infty} \ n  \cdot  f(n\alpha) > 0$ for example (see any book on continued fractions for proof)

Answer (score 0):

If we consider three or more multipliers f, then we have to consider increasing power of $n$:
$$
n^{k}f(n\alpha)f(n\beta)f(n\gamma)\qquad (*)
$$
Otherwise, if Littlewood conjecture is valid and still $k=1$, then the limit of the above product is zero thanks to the boundedness of $f(n\gamma)$.